# Do I understand this Function.prototype.call() code correctly?

Tags: javascript

The code:

```
var content = Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementsByTagName("p"), function(e) {
  return e.innerHTML;
});
```

It's from p. 367 of *JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, 6th ed.*

**Here's what I think is happening in this code.**

The variable `content` is being assigned the result of a `.map()` call on the `NodeList` of paragraph tags returned by `document.getElementsByTagName("p")`.

The `.map()` method is accessed from the `Array.prototype`, and its `this` value is set to be the paragraph tag `NodeList` using `.call()`. Since `.map()` applies a function that has access to `item, index, array`, the `e` in `function(e)` is the item of the `NodeList`.

So the `content` variable ends up being comprised of the result of `.innerHTML` calls on each of the `Element` type `Nodes` in the `NodeList` made up of paragraph tags in the current document.

`.innerHTML` will return the text of a given HTML element if it has no other nodes inside it. Otherwise it will return the HTML nodes inside it.

Is that correct? I've tried:

1. Reading the [MDN documentation on Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)
2. Searching Programmers SE I found [Misunderstanding Scope](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/165288/misunderstanding-scope-in-javascript), which I'm not certain how to interpret. It claims the MDN documentation is incomplete.
3. Reading more in the *Definitive* book.
4. Messing around in JSFiddle - the code acts as expected, I just want to know how it's doing what it does.

Comment: Yup, nailed it. You should edit your post to ask what is happening, and put your explanation in an answer.

Comment: It might also be interesting to know why the return value of [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) (a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList)) doesn't support Array methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Why_can't_I_use_forEach_or_map_on_a_NodeList.3F

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup, that's exactly that's happening.

Just to be *really* picky:

> `.innerHTML` will return the text of a given HTML element if it has no other nodes inside it. Otherwise it will return the HTML nodes inside it.

`.innerHTML` *always* returns the HTML contents of an element, regardless of whether it contains children or not. It's just hard to spot the difference between the text of an element and HTML of an element when it contains no children (but there is a difference!).

HTML:

```
<div>&lt;</div>
```

JS:

```
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML); // "&lt;"
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].textContent); // "<"
```

---

FWIW, this is possible in the first place because a lot of JavaScript methods prefer [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) to relying on inheritance

> When I see a bird that walks like a duck and swims like a duck and quacks like a duck, I call that bird a duck

Because of this, `map()` will happily let you `map()` any object which *feels* like an array (i.e. has a `.length` property).

You could also have used:

```
var content = [].map.call(document.getElementsByTagName("p"), function(e) { return e.innerHTML; });
```

... but the former is preferred because you don't have to create, then throwaway, the array to get access to the `map()` function.